# Question about MongoDB TTL background thread

Tags: mongodb

MongoDB 6.0.2, server 8 cores + 32GB RAM + SSD. We are inserting around 1.000 documents/second in a collection with a TTL index. The collection keeps growing because the rate of document inserts seems to be much greater than the rate of document deletion by TTL. Documentation says the background thread starts every 60s, but I can see documents that should have expired 10 minutes ago.

Is there any possible improvement to apply here? Or the only way to solve it is to increase cpu and memory on the server?

Thanks,

Joan.